# How to replace NAs in a dataframe with other columns

Tags: r

I want to merge columns to create a new column:

```
      x    y    z
1  A <NA> <NA>
2  <NA> B <NA>
49 <NA> <NA> C
50 <NA> <NA> C
```

I want the result:

```
      x    y    z m
1  A <NA> <NA> A
2  <NA> B <NA> B
49 <NA> <NA> C C
50 <NA> <NA> C C
```

I checked previous answers, they were all based on summing rows using is.na but it cannot apply to this case where the variable is a character.

Answer (score 2):

Using `coalesce` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$m <- coalesce(df$x, df$y, df$z)
```

`coalesce` behaves the same way as the SQL function, except for `NA` in R taking the place of `NULL` in SQL.  The above code will return the first non `NA` value from the `x`, `y`, and `z` columns, in that order.

For a pure base R option, we can try using `ifelse` with `is.na`:

```
df$m <- ifelse(!is.na(df$x), df$x,
            ifelse(!is.na(df$y), df$y, df$z))
```